# In Angular 5 project getting gyp errors on npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular5

I am trying "npm install" in angular 5 project, but its giving gyp errors . does anyone have any idea about the errors visible in the following screenshots.

[image: Image contains the detail of errors]

I have tried to clear cache , deleted package-lock and even installed and configured python 2. but nothing worked.

Comment: node-gyp requires python2. Install it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is failing at node-gyp which needs python, you can set the python path with npm install

```
npm install --python=python2.7
```